# Include missing weeks in Group By Query

Tags: sql-server, group-by

There are already similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479918/include-missing-months-in-group-by-query), but I can't seem to get it to work for me. Maybe because I have several tables to join on.

Either way here is my query:

```
    DECLARE     @StartDate datetime2, @EndDate datetime2;
SET     @StartDate = DateAdd(day, -7, GETDATE());
SET     @EndDate = DateAdd(year, 1, GETDATE());

WITH    Weeks AS
(
        SELECT  @StartDate AS WeekDate
        UNION   ALL
        SELECT  DATEADD(day, 7, WeekDate)
        FROM    Weeks
        WHERE   DATEADD(day, 7, WeekDate) <= @EndDate
)
SELECT      WeekDate AS WeekOfSRUs
            ,ISNULL(COUNT(i.incident_id), 0) AS SRUCount
            --,i.incident_id
            ,ic.inc_cat_sc
FROM        Weeks
            ,incident i
            ,JPTSYS_WEB_CUST_PROP_CONT
            ,JPTSYS_WEB_CUST_PROP
            ,JPTSYS_WEB_LKUP_DATA
            ,JPTSYS_WEB_LKUP
            ,JPTSYS_WEB_CUST_PROP_MULT
            ,inc_cat ic
WHERE       (i.INCIDENT_ID=JPTSYS_WEB_CUST_PROP_CONT.ENTITY_ID AND
            JPTSYS_WEB_CUST_PROP_CONT.JPTSYS_WEB_CUST_PROP_ID=JPTSYS_WEB_CUST_PROP.JPTSYS_WEB_CUST_PROP_ID AND  
            JPTSYS_WEB_CUST_PROP_CONT.SINGLE_SEL_VAL_ID=JPTSYS_WEB_LKUP_DATA.JPTSYS_WEB_LKUP_DATA_ID AND
            JPTSYS_WEB_CUST_PROP.JPTSYS_WEB_LKUP_ID=JPTSYS_WEB_LKUP.JPTSYS_WEB_LKUP_ID AND
            JPTSYS_WEB_LKUP_DATA.JPTSYS_WEB_LKUP_DATA_ID=JPTSYS_WEB_CUST_PROP_MULT.JPTSYS_WEB_LKUP_DATA_ID AND
            JPTSYS_WEB_CUST_PROP.JPTSYS_WEB_CUST_PROP_ID =59) AND
            (JPTSYS_WEB_CUST_PROP_CONT.DATE_VAL >= WeekDate AND JPTSYS_WEB_CUST_PROP_CONT.DATE_VAL < DATEADD(day, 7, WeekDate)) AND
            (inc_cat_sc = 'R1A DESKTOPMIN' OR inc_cat_sc = 'R1B DESKTOPMAJ' OR inc_cat_sc = 'R8A CRTPATCH-DT') AND i.inc_cat_id = ic.inc_cat_id
GROUP BY    ic.inc_cat_sc, Weeks.WeekDate
ORDER BY    Weeks.WeekDate
```

And the results:

```
WeekOfSRUs                  SRUCount   inc_cat_sc
2013-01-25 10:06:57.2370000    4       R1A DESKTOPMIN
2013-01-25 10:06:57.2370000    1       R1B DESKTOPMAJ
2013-02-01 10:06:57.2370000    4       R1A DESKTOPMIN
2013-02-08 10:06:57.2370000    2       R1A DESKTOPMIN
2013-02-08 10:06:57.2370000    1       R1B DESKTOPMAJ
2013-02-15 10:06:57.2370000    3       R1A DESKTOPMIN
2013-02-15 10:06:57.2370000    2       R1B DESKTOPMAJ
2013-02-15 10:06:57.2370000    2       R8A CRTPATCH-DT
2013-02-22 10:06:57.2370000    3       R1A DESKTOPMIN
2013-02-22 10:06:57.2370000    4       R1B DESKTOPMAJ
2013-03-01 10:06:57.2370000    5       R1A DESKTOPMIN
2013-03-08 10:06:57.2370000    4       R1A DESKTOPMIN
2013-03-15 10:06:57.2370000    2       R8A CRTPATCH-DT
2013-03-22 10:06:57.2370000    1       R1A DESKTOPMIN
2013-03-29 10:06:57.2370000    1       R1B DESKTOPMAJ
2013-05-03 10:06:57.2370000    1       R1B DESKTOPMAJ
2013-05-10 10:06:57.2370000    1       R1A DESKTOPMIN
```

As for all the tables referenced this is a contracted product that we are forced to use and have no control over the database design/schema. I'm told these joins are necessary to get the specific field I'm looking for because it was a custom field added after installation.

From the link I posted above I modified my query to `LEFT JOIN` all those tables but I still got the same results.

I'm fairly new to intermediate/advanced SQL so please be nice. If I've left out any information I will gladly add it to get this to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clarify what results you are expecting I.e. are you expecting every week for every inc_cat_sc?
If so, you will need to cross Join all weeks for the date period you are looking at and use a where clause to produce the count.

Comment: Yes I am looking for every week for every inc_cat_sc. I'm not familiar with how to cross join, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

you have to make a outer join with the "inc_cat ic"

if you want every week for every "ic.inc_cat_sc"

including if the count(i.incident_id) is 0

try change the

```
AND i.inc_cat_id = ic.inc_cat_id
```

for

```
AND i.inc_cat_id =* ic.inc_cat_id
```

the inc_cat_sc is a collumn from ic.inc_cat_sc right?

Comment: That gives me an error about using non-ANSI outer join operators. How would I write the outer join with all those other tables included?