# Create PHP arrays with dates and number of orders extracted by month from SQL

Tags: php, sql, arrays, date, monthcalendar

I have a table called 'orders' with multiple rows with different dates.

I want to build a graph with number of orders per month, so I need to query an array that looks like this:

- Jan ------- 3
- Feb ------- 1
- Mar ------- 0
- Apr ------- 8
  ......

As seen, even when there are no orders, the Month is showing.

From there, I would need to load the amounts of the array into something like this:

```
$data1y=array(3,1,0,8...);
```

While I will have an array of months like this:

```
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels(array('Jan','Feb','March','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'));
```

I tried with a SQL like this one, but no luck:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders GROUP BY month(date)
```

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders GROUP BY month(date) ....what is given you as result

Comment: This question explains the concept of how to do what you want in MS SQL: [Include missing months in Group By query](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11479918)

Comment: Create an array that lists the months as keys, then use the results from SQL to populate the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should something like this:

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y%m') AS `Ym`, COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM `orders`
GROUP BY `Ym`
```

<kbd>**[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4e1a/1)**</kbd>

p.s. You can fill missing months in PHP, or in SQL like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11480291/67332).

Comment: this one looks great. How could I assign only the counts to the array '$data1y=array()'?

Comment: I'm fetching like: "$orders = $ordersQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)"

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [Ym] => December [count] => 7 ) [1] => Array ( [Ym] => November [count] => 11 ) [2] => Array ( [Ym] => October [count] => 9 ) [3] => Array ( [Ym] => September [count] => 8 ) [4] => Array ( [Ym] => August [count] => 9 ) [5] => Array ( [Ym] => July [count] => 1 ) [6] => Array ( [Ym] => May [count] => 2 ) [7] => Array ( [Ym] => April [count] => 1 ) )

Comment: That would be great but I am on PHP 5.2, so DateTime::createFromFormat is not supported...

Comment: @samyb8: then create SQL query like in [this example](https://eval.in/80385), this should work on 5.2.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the whole thing in PHP after using a query like:-

```
SELECT date FROM orders
```

If after you have run, for example, `PDOStatement::fetchAll()`, you have an array called $dateArray containing the dates in your DB, then you could do something like:-

```
$countArray = ['Jan' => 0, 'Feb' => 0, 'Mar' => 0, 'Apr' => 0, 'May' => 0, 'Jun' => 0, 'Jul' => 0, 'Aug' => 0, 'Sep' => 0, 'Oct' => 0, 'Nov' => 0, 'Dec' => 0];
foreach($dateArray as $dateString){
    $date = new \DateTime($dateString);
    $countArray[$date->format('M')]++;
}
```

[I have setup a working example here](http://3v4l.org/iaAq1).

See the PHP manual for more information on the [DateTime classes](http://php.net/datetime) and [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).