# TSQL - Return Records for each of the Months between Start and End Dates even if no data available for that month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My current SELECT query result is as follows

```
SELECT Category, MonthYear, Percentage 
FROM #Result
```

With `@StartDate` as **2018-12-01** and @EndDate as **2019-05-01**

```
Category  | MonthYear  | Percentage
----------+------------+------------    
Category1 | 2018-12-01 | 80 
Category1 | 2019-01-01 | 70
Category1 | 2019-02-01 | 75
Category1 | 2019-03-01 | 60
Category1 | 2019-04-01 | 45
Category1 | 2019-05-01 | 29
Category2 | 2019-03-01 | 78
Category2 | 2019-04-01 | 95
Category2 | 2019-05-01 | 98
```

But I would like my result to have all months between `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` for each of the `Categories` with percentage value as zero if no data exists for that category.

```
Category  | MonthYear  | Percentage
----------+------------+------------    
Category1 | 2018-12-01 | 80 
Category1 | 2019-01-01 | 70
Category1 | 2019-02-01 | 75
Category1 | 2019-03-01 | 60
Category1 | 2019-04-01 | 45
Category1 | 2019-05-01 | 29
Category2 | 2018-12-01 | 0
Category2 | 2019-01-01 | 0
Category2 | 2019-02-01 | 0
Category2 | 2019-03-01 | 78
Category2 | 2019-04-01 | 95
Category2 | 2019-05-01 | 98
```

Comment: Show the query that populates #result... that's most likely where the change is needed

Comment: Hi perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479918/include-missing-months-in-group-by-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to generate the dates.  Then use `cross join` and `left join` to bring in the data.  So:

```
with dates as (
      select min(monthyear) as yyyymm, max(monthyear) as max_yyyymm
      from t
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, yyyymm), max_yyyymm
      from dates
      where yyyymm < max_yyyymm
    )
select c.category, d.yyyymm, coalesce(t.percentage, 0) as percentage
from (select distinct category from t) c cross join
     dates d left join
     t
     on t.category = c.category and t.monthyear = d.yyyymm
order by c.category, d.yyyymm;
```

Comment: I think `ISNULL()` would be more appropriate here instead of `COALESCE()`.

Comment: @AdnanSharif Why? `COALESCE()` is ANSI standard, while `ISNULL()` is both proprietary and confusingly shares a name with [a differently-working function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isnull-function) in another Microsoft language.

Comment: Perfect @gordon-linoff , This is what i'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @AaronBertrand I don't understand why we shouldn't use `ISNULL()` when it is more readable and appropriate in this case.

Comment: More readable to who? Seems subjective. More appropriate? Why? Can you give a concrete reason why `ISNULL` is "more appropriate" other than "I like it better"?

Comment: `Isnull` is an intrinsic function and `coalesce` is sugar for a case statement. It rarely makes a difference, but sometimes it leads to different performance. Especially when it comes to function that have non-deterministic output. As for sharing a name with a VB function, I don't particularly think that's anyone's concern.

Comment: @AdnanSharif . . . I think standard functions are more readable.  Period.  They are documented and used much more widely.  That  being said, there are some specific circumstances where `isnull()` is better for performance reasons.  This is not one of those situations.

Comment: Thanks for the information, guys. @GordonLinoff it would be helpful for me if you tell me in which cases we should use `ISNULL()` over `COALESCE()` for better performance.

Comment: @AdnanSharif . . . I wrote `COALESCE()` in the answer.  It is more flexible than `ISNULL()` (because it accepts multiple arguments and is standard).  You want to use `ISNULL()` specifically when performance is an issue, and that would be when the first argument is a very complicated expression, such as a subquery or complex function).

Comment: @Adnan There’s only one case that I know of, and it’s a bad pattern anyway. There are other minor differences but for the most part, in the standard two-option scenario, they are interchangeable. COALESCE has other advantages over ISNULL so, outside of that one very specific edge case, COALESCE is going to be a better choice. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/

Comment: Thank you so very much. I didn't know about these before. Thanks. :)